# Azure storage table max partition and max row key

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

What is the maximum partition key we can have in 1 Azure Storage table

Comment: What do you mean by maximum?

Comment: How many partition key we can have in 1 table storage. ie. can we have 10000 unique partition key?

Comment: As such there’s no limit on the number of the partitions you can have.

Comment: @LenroyYeung Do the provided inputs help?

Comment: @LenroyYeung Happy to help! Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of partition keys in a single table per se.

From the docs:

> Locate data that your client application does not insert, update, or query in the same logical unit of work (that is, in a single query or batch update) in separate partitions. **Keep in mind that there is no limit to the number of partition keys in a single table, so having millions of partition keys is not a problem and will not impact performance**. For example, if your application is a popular website with user login, using the User ID as the partition key could be a good choice.

Check [Performance and scalability checklist for Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/storage-performance-checklist#tables-and-partitions) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a unlimited partition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).